# I have a query but it doesn't work. How can I write it correctly?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

There are three tables in total. I wrote the following query to combine these three tables.I want to write a sql statement to show the employees who worked in the IT department and earn more than the average salary. My statement is below. But when the statement runs, I get a "no data found" warning. How can I write this correctly?

```
`select 
 e.FIRST_NAME 
,e.LAST_NAME
,c.DEPARTMENT_NAME
,l.CITY
,l.STATE_PROVINCE
,k.COUNTRY_NAME
,e.SALARY 
 from hr.employees e join hr.departments c on (c.DEPARTMENT_ID=e.DEPARTMENT_ID) 
 join hr.locations l on (c.LOCATION_ID=l.LOCATION_ID) 
 join hr.countries k on (k.COUNTRY_ID=l.COUNTRY_ID) where DEPARTMENT_NAME='IT' 
 and SALARY in (select SALARY from hr.employees group by SALARY having SALARY > AVG(SALARY));`
```

Comment: and salary > (select avg(salary)  ... )

Comment: _earn more than the average salary_ - IT department average or company average?

Comment: I used company average

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for company's average salary:

```
select 
 e.FIRST_NAME 
,e.LAST_NAME
,c.DEPARTMENT_NAME
,l.CITY
,l.STATE_PROVINCE
,k.COUNTRY_NAME
,e.SALARY 
 from hr.employees e join hr.departments c on (c.DEPARTMENT_ID=e.DEPARTMENT_ID) 
 join hr.locations l on (c.LOCATION_ID=l.LOCATION_ID) 
 join hr.countries k on (k.COUNTRY_ID=l.COUNTRY_ID) where DEPARTMENT_NAME='IT' 
 and SALARY > (select avg(SALARY) from hr.employees);
```